# How to connect with mysql server.......?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, wampserver

Hello friends I'd installed WAMP server and I changed root password and now it is saying that. Can't connect to SQL server password or username is wrong.

Comment: Have you changed root password in your code?

Comment: But the error comes in phpmyadmin when I open phpmyadmin it shows the error

Comment: @DomnickToretto : Do check whether you have provided the the correct `password` for corresponding `user`.

Answer (score 0):

After changing MySQL password you need to set the password in `config.inc.php` of phpMyAdmin because the default `root` password is `""` (empty). So now goto

`C:\wamp\phpmyadmin\` directory and open `config.inc.php` in any text editor and find out

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root'; // MySQL user
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = ''; // MySQL password change this with new password
```

After that save and exit from text editor. Now restart your **Wamp Server** and try to access MySQL through phpMyAdmin.

For more visit [Changing `config.ini.php`](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,14434,71909)